# Cómo llamar a un procedimiento de sql desde php usando sqlsrvr

Tags: php, sql

¿Cómo puedo llamar a ese procedimiento almacenado en sql server usando php y sqlsrv?

Tengo el procedimiento:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[japTI_sp_Facebook_ConsultarColonias]
     @Buscar_Colonia   nvarchar(100) = null
AS
BEGIN
    if @Buscar_Colonia = ''
        set @Buscar_Colonia = null

    Select
      col.COLONIA_ID                 as Colonia_ID
    , col.NOMBRE                     as Colonia
     from  Cat_Cor_Colonias          as col
     where col.ESTATUS = 'ACTIVO'
     and ((@Buscar_Colonia is null) or (col.NOMBRE collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI like '%' + @Buscar_Colonia + '%'))
     order by col.NOMBRE
END
```

Y en mi archivo conectar.php tengo:

```
<?php 
/* Nombre del servidor. */
$serverName = "nombre_servidor";
/* Usuario y clave.  */
$uid = "usuario";
$pwd = "password_prueba";
/* Array asociativo con la información de la conexion */
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
"PWD"=>$pwd,
"Database"=>"SCOM_0");

/* Nos conectamos mediante la autenticación de SQL Server . */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
echo "No es posible conectarse al servidor.</br>";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}else{

    $sql = "EXEC dbo.japTI_sp_Facebook_ConsultarColonias @Buscar_Colonia = ?";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params);
    if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
        echo "Your code is fail!";
        die;
    }
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_rows($stmt)){
        //Stuff
    }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún error, o por qué no te permite conectarte con el SP?

Comment: solo no sé como implementar ese procedimiento dentro de php

Answer (score 0):

PRUEBA CON ESTO

```
$companiesSQL = "{call LE()}";
$REC = SQLSRV_PREPARE ($conn, $companiesSQL);
                            SQLSRV_EXECUTE($REC);
```

Comment: Trata de agregar una explicación a tu respuesta para mejorar su calidad